# Observable.ObserveOn() appears to have no effect

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to use use Rx to process items in parallel. It seems I can't tell Rx to run my observer's OnNext() in parallel. 
Here is test code to demonstrate

```
[Test]
public void ObservableObserveOnNewThreadRunsInParallel()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    // store items as they are output
    var list = new List<Tuple<string, int, int, int, TimeSpan>>();

    // used to wait until a sequences are complete
    var ev = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    // try these schedulers
    var schedulers = new[] {
                                Tuple.Create("ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance", (IScheduler)ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance),
                                Tuple.Create("NewThreadScheduler.Default", (IScheduler)NewThreadScheduler.Default),
                                Tuple.Create("TaskPoolScheduler.Default", (IScheduler)TaskPoolScheduler.Default),
                                Tuple.Create("Scheduler.Default", (IScheduler)Scheduler.Default),
                                Tuple.Create("Scheduler.Immediate", (IScheduler)Scheduler.Immediate),
                            };

    // try each scheduler
    foreach (var schedulerTuple in
        schedulers) {

        // emit tuples <i, delay> where delay decreases with each new tuple
        // such that output timing is expected to be reversed
        var observable =
            Observable.Range(0, 5)
                .Select(i => Tuple.Create((int)i, (int)(500 - i * 100)))
                .Take(5);

        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        Tuple<string, IScheduler> scheduler = schedulerTuple;


        observable
            // specify the scheduler to use
            .ObserveOn(schedulerTuple.Item2)
            .Subscribe(
                v => {
                    // emulate some work (first items take longer than last items)
                    Thread.Sleep(v.Item2);

                    // record when the item is done recording
                    lock (list)
                        list.Add(
                            Tuple.Create(
                                scheduler.Item1,
                                v.Item1,
                                v.Item2,
                                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                                dt - DateTime.Now));
                },
                // let the test go on
                () => ev.Set());

        // wait until the end of the sequence
        ev.WaitOne();
    }

    // print observed order
    foreach (var i in list) {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

And the output :

```
Starting thread: 5
(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance, 0, 500, 9, -00:00:04.2514251)
(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance, 1, 400, 9, -00:00:04.6524652)
(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance, 2, 300, 9, -00:00:04.9524952)
(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance, 3, 200, 9, -00:00:05.1525152)
(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance, 4, 100, 9, -00:00:05.2525252)
(NewThreadScheduler.Default, 0, 500, 11, -00:00:06.5066506)
(NewThreadScheduler.Default, 1, 400, 11, -00:00:06.9066906)
(NewThreadScheduler.Default, 2, 300, 11, -00:00:07.2067206)
(NewThreadScheduler.Default, 3, 200, 11, -00:00:07.4067406)
(NewThreadScheduler.Default, 4, 100, 11, -00:00:07.5067506)
(TaskPoolScheduler.Default, 0, 500, 12, -00:00:00.5020502)
(TaskPoolScheduler.Default, 1, 400, 12, -00:00:00.9020902)
(TaskPoolScheduler.Default, 2, 300, 12, -00:00:01.2021202)
(TaskPoolScheduler.Default, 3, 200, 12, -00:00:01.4021402)
(TaskPoolScheduler.Default, 4, 100, 12, -00:00:01.5021502)
(Scheduler.Default, 0, 500, 13, -00:00:00.5020502)
(Scheduler.Default, 1, 400, 13, -00:00:00.9020902)
(Scheduler.Default, 2, 300, 13, -00:00:01.2021202)
(Scheduler.Default, 3, 200, 13, -00:00:01.4021402)
(Scheduler.Default, 4, 100, 13, -00:00:01.5021502)
(Scheduler.Immediate, 0, 500, 5, -00:00:00.5020502)
(Scheduler.Immediate, 1, 400, 5, -00:00:00.9040904)
(Scheduler.Immediate, 2, 300, 5, -00:00:01.2041204)
(Scheduler.Immediate, 3, 200, 5, -00:00:01.4041404)
(Scheduler.Immediate, 4, 100, 5, -00:00:01.5041504)
```

Notice how each OnNext call appear to have waited on the previous call even though I explicitly use `ObserveOn()` to specify the scheduler to use for notifications.

I expected all but Scheduler.Immediate to run the notifications in parallel.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

This is by design. One of Rx's primary contracts is that all notifications must be serialized.

See §§4.2, 6.7 in the [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219).

Observables represent concurrency in Rx, so to have overlapping notifications requires two or more observables. Notifications won't overlap in the same observer, but they'll overlap with respect to each observer.

For instance, if you need to execute two methods (observers) concurrently, then you need to define two observables.

Technically, it's the observers (subscriptions) not the observables that are needed for concurrency; therefore, subscribing to the same *cold* observable twice can produce concurrency, depending upon the scheduler used by the observable; however, subscribing to the same *hot* observable twice does not result in concurrency. (See my blog post: [Hot and Cold Observables](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx).)

**ObserveOn** introduces concurrency when passed a concurrency-introducing scheduler. But how can it do that without violating the §6.7 contract? Well, it splits the observable into two observables: *before* the operator and *after* the operator! Alternatively, you can look at it as two subscriptions or observers: *before* and *after*. The *before* observer is an internal observer that **ObserveOn** provides. The *after* observer is your observer, or the observer provided by the next operator in the query.

No matter how you look at it, the notifications in the *before* observable can occur concurrently with respect to the notifications in the *after* observable. But the *after* observer will only receive serialized notifications in the context of the *after* observable.

Comment: I understand the Rx guidelines are the reason behind the synchronization of my notifications. However, I must admit you got me lost with your before/after observables.

Comment: On the other hand, I now understand why I can demonstrate concurrency using SelectMany async callbacks. SelectMany subscribes to sub-observables and ensures their notifications are synchronized with regards to its own subscribers

Comment: Think about how you would implement an operator yourself with help from the `Create` method. In the simplest case, you must call `Subscribe` on the observable passed to your operator. That's the `before` observable. Your operator returns an observable. That's the `after` observable. The `ObserveOn` operator observes notifications from the `before` observable and schedules them in the `after` observable (typically by inserting a queue or by relying on a native asynchronous queue provided by a `SynchronizationContext`). Is that a bit clearer?

Comment: Note that two subscriptions are made: When you call `Subscribe` on the `ObserveOn` operator's observable, it calls `Subscribe` on the source observable. Two observers (subscriptions) are required in Rx for concurrency to be present.

Comment: I do understand but I still find the wording quite unclear. Throwing in hot and cold observables in the mix makes it just more complicated.  I'd write it as : To respect the RX Impl Guidelines esp. §§4.2, 6.7, every observable implementation need to ensure the notification it sends out never overlap regardless of the scheduler used to hand them out to subscribers. As such, a subscriber of RX will never observe actual concurrency (calls in parallel) even though each notification may run on different threads.

Comment: Observable implementations include RX operators (Select, SelectMany, Merge etc ...) as well as custom implementations (eg. created with Observable.Create)

Comment: Well, that's just repeating what's already in the Rx Design Guidelines. And I didn't just throw temperature into the mix. It's been carefully thought out. Side effects are what defines temperature, and it's the temperature that controls whether concurrency is available when subscribing to the same observable more than once. Very important. I was providing an exhaustive analysis, which I haven't seen before for this particular question (which has been asked several times in the past already, as I'm sure you can imagine. :-)