# Consuming values concurrently emmited by an Observer

Tags: java, java-8, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm learning reactive programming with RxJava, and want to consume emmited values concurrently withouth blocking in a single execution thread.

```
        Observable
            .interval(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .take(5)
            .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Long counter) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Got: " + counter + " thread : "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            });

    sleep(10000);
```

I'll get this output

```
Got: 0 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-1
Got: 1 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-1
Got: 2 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-1
Got: 3 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-1
Got: 4 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-1
```

how do i handle each event in async? like this

```
Got: 0 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-1
Got: 1 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-2
Got: 2 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-3
Got: 3 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-4
Got: 4 thread : RxComputationThreadPool-5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rx, an observable represents concurrency<sup>1</sup>, so to process notifications concurrently with respect to each other, you must project each notification into an observable.

`flatMap` is the asynchronous sequential composition operator. It projects each notification from a source observable into an observable, thus allowing you to process each input value concurrently. It then merges the results of each computation into a flattened observable sequence with non-overlapping notifications.

*Addendum:*

In the `selector` for `flatMap`, there are often multiple ways to create a concurrent observable depending upon the target platform. I don't know Java, but in .NET you would typically either use `Observable.Start` to introduce concurrency or an asynchronous method (`async/await`) to take advantage of native asynchrony, which is often preferable.

<sup>1</sup> Technically, an individual subscription (observer) for a *cold* observable enables concurrency in Rx, though it's often convenient to think in terms of observables instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549737/observable-observeon-appears-to-have-no-effect/27551571#27551571) for more info.

Comment: could you suggest the change i need to do to get desired behaviour? I think it will be much easy to understand with actual example...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Java, but in .NET it would look something like `xs.FlatMap(x => ProcessAsync(x)).Subscribe()`, where `ProcessAsync` is a method that accepts `x` as an argument and returns an observable of any type. You can also call `Subscribe` without any parameters just for its side effects, assuming that you have no need to process the return values of each call to `ProcessAsync`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some more information.